# Add/Remove # (hash) from crontab

Tags: sed, centos, cron

What is the best way to add and remove a hash symbol (#) from the crontab? I'd like to have a one liner that is capable of commenting all the cronjobs at once and if needed, uncomment them. It's a CentOS distro.

I think the best option is to use 'sed' but I'm not entirely sure how it'd work with the crontab.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* do something like `sed -e 's/^#//g' -i /etc/crontab` ... `sed -e 's/^/#/g' -i /etc/crontab` — assuming that your crontab file has *no* actual comments in it.

Safer to use a sentinel like `s/^/#disabled: /g` & `s/^#disabled: //g`

Even safer to put the "affected" cron entries into a file in `/etc/cron.d/` and move that file in/out of the directory as-needed. `mv /usr/local/etc/special-cron-jobs /etc/cron.d/` ; `mv /etc/cron.d/special-cron-jobs /usr/local/etc`

If you're just trying to disable them all, you could also just stop `cron` itself, using

```
service anacron stop
```

(*`anacron` may not be right on CentOS?)